# macOS Sierra: ${TAIL} is not working in zsh

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I was trying to execute some bash scripts in zsh (oh-my-zsh). I found ${TAIL} is not working in zsh.

bash:

> bash-3.2$ ${CD} /tmp; echo "test" >> test.txt; ${TAIL} test.txt
>   bash: /tmp: is a directory
>   test

zsh:

> ~ ${CD} /tmp; echo "test" >> test.txt; ${TAIL} test.txt
>   zsh: command not found: tail -f
>    ✘ /tmp

But using tail directly is fine

> ✘  /tmp tail -f test.txt
>   test
>   test
>
> whereis tail
>   /usr/bin/tail
>    echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a classic case in `zsh` for [Why does $var where var="foo bar" not do what I expect?](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html)

Unlike `bash`, by default, `zsh` does not split into words when passed to a command or used in a loop as `for foo in $var`.

```
var="foo bar"
```

enabled the flag manually as

```
setopt shwordsplit
```

then try the same as

```
echo "test" >> test.txt; ${TAIL} test.txt
```